# suspicious activity is blocked from antivirus when adding websites in host file in windows - C#

Tags: c#, windows, url, host, blocking

When I try to add sites in the host file, Manually I can. But when I tried with C# code, the antivirus blocks it. Is there any way to override this process? Attached image for your reference.

[Message from Kaspersky antivirus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQFyS.png)

Sample application: **https://github.com/Elanchezhiyan-AIT/BlockUrlViaForms**

In the above attached git code, You can try example button so that the issue can be reproduced.

*Note: Any one antivirus should be installed. I have tried with Kaspersky antivirus.*

How can we override this kind of activity?

Comment: I would agree with Kaspersky that writing to the hosts file is a suspicious activity. Maybe whitelisting your program in the AV helps.

Comment: @KlausGütter, We do have a number of antiviruses available on the internet. If whitelisting is the only process to get rid of this error, do we have any commonplace where we can configure it?

I hope - each antivirus has a different process for whitelisting.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to windows applications if your app does not have a trusted certificate, certain antivirus programs will block it. Others will give a warning saying it from a non trusted developer.

If you disable Kaspersky or whatever anti virus you have it should work. It's just that the app your building doesn't have a signature that aligns as "SAFE" signature.

That's all an antivirus is essentially is a database of signatures. If the signature is attached to an SSL and/or Certificate you are good. If it doesn't then it's blocked.

You can also add your program to the firewall and have it listed as safe and it will run on your computer. However, for it to run on other computers it's wise to get the certificate so it is not booted by antivirus programs.

Comment: Having the program signed will give you some credits in the AV's evaluation of risk, but there have been signed malware around so the AV will not use it as sole criterion. Interesting read: https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/research/18/d/understanding-code-signing-abuse-in-malware-campaigns.html

Comment: Way way back in the day (2005) when I started developing in C# that was the main reason. However, times have changed. But applications without a signed certificate that was the main reason. If you plan on publishing to the Microsoft Store I think now they give you the certificate. However, if it installed else where (website) you had to have the certificate (best practices).. they may have changed over the years. I only publish through the store so times may have changed over the years.

Comment: @CampNerd

If we purchase a signed certificate and add it to the build, Will it allow access to the HOST file to edit or update it?

Comment: The certificate just says it's from a verified developer. So the concept is once you sign it when publishing should be enough but having a Certificate gives a little more trust... See this from the MSDN ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: If your app is being put on the windows store it has to signed "ClickSigned" but one you get a certificate, your app goes into a review and if it's not malicious it will be granted the Certificate a signature. That signature is a "safe" signature that the antivirus will ignore. The click sign when publishing in theory is enough but getting the certificate is a little more trusting and allows more versatility when installing on client computers on a network. Because your changing file structure adding things to the root